# Issue enabling accesslog overlay with Openldap 2.4.21

Tags: logging, ldap, ubuntu-10.04, openldap

I'm running `openldap 2.4.21` on `ubuntu server 10.04` and trying to enable the accesslog overlay using the `cn=config` configuration style (so not `slapd.conf`). My main database is `olcDatabase={1}hdb` so I defined the following module:

```
/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/cn=module{2}.ldif

# accesslog overlay definitions for primary db
dn: olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}hdb
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcAccessLogConfig
olcOverlay: accesslog
olcAccessLogDB: cn=accesslog
olcAccessLogOps: writes
olcAccessLogSuccess: TRUE
# scan the accesslog DB every day, and purge entries older than 7 days
olcAccessLogPurge: 07+00:00 01+00:00
```

I got these [configuration directives from this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) so I'm assuming they are good. When I start `slapd` I get the below errors:

```
Nov 30 07:10:17 server slapd[11604]: UNKNOWN attributeDescription "OLCACCESSLOGDB" inserted.
Nov 30 07:10:17 server slapd[11604]: UNKNOWN attributeDescription "OLCACCESSLOGOPS" inserted.
Nov 30 07:10:17 server slapd[11604]: UNKNOWN attributeDescription "OLCACCESSLOGSUCCESS" inserted.
Nov 30 07:10:17 server slapd[11604]: UNKNOWN attributeDescription "OLCACCESSLOGPURGE" inserted.
Nov 30 07:10:17 server slapd[11604]: config error processing olcOverlay=accesslog,olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config:
```

It looks to me like I'm missing a schema, however when I search for a schema containing the aforementioned attributes I find nothing

```
$ grep -iR "LOGDB" /etc/ldap/schema/
-
```

**Can someone tell me what I'm missing please?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstood what the Accesslog overlay does. It writes access information of one db to another db. So if you are trying to monitor access to {1}hdb, you will have to setup a second database where accesslog will write the information.

Create a directory called accesslog under /var/lib/ldap/

```
mkdir /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
chown -R openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
```

Then use the following ldif to setup the second database

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap/accesslog
olcSuffix: cn=accesslog
olcRootDN: cn=root,dc=yourdomain,dc=com
olcDbIndex: default eq
olcDbIndex: entryCSN,objectClass,reqEnd,reqResult,reqStart
```

Comment: I keep getting `adding new entry "olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config"
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21)
 additional info: objectClass: value #1 invalid per syntax` I wish I understood what that meant, I get the impression a java library is supposed to be the sole method of interacting with ldap

Comment: I could have the wrong tree to bark up too; is this a good way of seeing what queries ldap clients are running as to debug why a black box client isn't getting results that another client does?

Answer (score 0):

I bet you did write those attributes IN CAPITAL LETTERS. OpenLDAP is not a big fan of YELLING, but appreciates case-sensitive attributes.

So, for example, instead of `OLCACCESSLOGDB` use `olcAccessLogDB`.

Comment: No I did not, the attributes are written in camel case as shown in my sample module file. The camel case syntax is what's used for other slapd.d configuration files which run fine so I would be surprised if that was the problem.